# How to create cordova application(version 3.5.0) in android using CLI?

Tags: android, cordova, installation

I have tried to create the `cordova` latest application using command line interface. When I tried to build the application using CLI, the following error occurs:

> -pre-compile:
> <
>   BUILD FAILED
>   C:\Users\user\Desktop\HelloAndroid\platforms\android\custom_rules.xml:5: Reference project.all.jars.path not found.
>   Total time: 2 seconds
>   Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,ant,debug,-f,
> C:\Users\user\Desktop\HelloAndroid\platforms\android\build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
>   Error: C:\Users\user\Desktop\HelloAndroid\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: 
> Command failed with exit code 2
>       at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:135:23)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
>       at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
>   C:\Users\user\Desktop\HelloAndroid>

Comment: Do you have all the prereqs installed? Git? Ant? A JDK? Android SDK?

Comment: Yes. I have already installed and set the path in environment variable also.